# PySpark: Reading and joining from two datasets using user-delegated SAS tokens in databricks

Tags: azure, authentication, pyspark, databricks, sas-token

I am using following code to read from two datasets(lying on datalake) using SAS tokens.
I am successfully able to read these dataset, but when I join between them, the authentication error is raised.

Steps:

1. Set spark config for 1st dataset. (using sas token for 1st dataset)
2. read dataset
3. display dataset
4. set spark config for 2nd dataset. (using sas token for 2nd dataset)
5. read dataset
6. display dataset
7. join and show dataset

Now, It works fine till step-6 but fails on step-7.
I believe the reason is on step-4, when I set config for 2nd dataset, the config for 1st dataset gets overwritten and hence, on step-7 when an action is performed using dataset-1, the authentication error occurs.

```
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("test-app").getOrCreate()
datalake_name = "MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT"

container_name = "MY_CONTAINER_NAME"

#################  Common Configs  ###########################

spark_session.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.auth.type.{datalake_name}.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")

spark_session.conf.set(f"fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.{datalake_name}.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")

################   Dataframe 1 Read   ##############################

spark_session.conf.set(f"fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.{datalake_name}.dfs.core.windows.net", "FIRST SAS TOKEN")

target_file_path = f"abfss://{container_name}@{datalake_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/folder_1/test_data"

df1 = spark_session.read.format("parquet").load(target_file_path)

#################  Dataframe 2 Read  ###############################

spark_session.conf.set(f"fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.{datalake_name}.dfs.core.windows.net", "SECOND SAS TOKEN")

target_file_path = f"abfss://{container_name}@{datalake_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/folder_2/test_data"

df2 = spark_session.read.format("parquet").load(target_file_path)



df3 = df2.join(df1)

df3.show()
```

Has anyone else ever faced this issue before?
What should be the correct way to perform this?
Please advise

Comment: you can use a single sas token on container level if your dta is in same storage account.
Why you are using 2 different token? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Yes, there is a specific reason. the data sources can be in multiple containers. i.e., one table in container 1 and other in container 2. Also, we do not want to provision container level token as this gives access to all data lying in that container, rather we want to restrict users to specific directories.

Answer (score 0):

It overwrites the Spark configuration when setting the Spark configuration for the second dataset. This may be the reason for the authentication error while joining two data frames. If the datasets are in one container, generate SAS at the container level as shown below:

[image]

Set Spark configuration with the generated SAS and join two data frames using the code below:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.<containerName>.<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net", "<SAS token>")
file_path = "folder1/cars.parquet"
file_path2 = "folder2/mt cars.parquet"
df2 = spark.read.format("parquet").load("wasbs://files@badls.blob.core.windows.net/" + file_path)
df1 = spark.read.format("parquet").load("wasbs://files@badls.blob.core.windows.net/" + file_path2)
df3 = df1.join(df2)
df3.show()
```

This will join the two data frames successfully as shown below:

[image]

Comment: No, we do not want to use container level token to restrict access. Also, the tables can be in multiple containers   i.e., one table in container 1 and other in container 2.  How do we set 2 user-delegated SAS tokens at directory level in spark configuration.

Comment: If the containers are different instead of setting configuration mount the path in databricks and use that path.

Comment: Mounting is deprecated in databricks.. Also, Mounting data gives access to everyone using that cluster raising security concerns.

Comment: Do you have a way where I can set two sas tokens in spark configuration at the same time?

Comment: AFAIK No you can set only one configuration at same time